# Passing state params between child states with same controller

Tags: angularjs, view, nested, angular-ui-router, state

Working on a project and it is the first time implementing ui-router.
The situation is, I have parent child states and all childs share same controller because all are working on same domain(CRUD).

The problem is, I am on list page where I click edit option and then state changes to

> /states/edit/1

Fine, but all my list, edit and update functions are in same controller. When state changes to states.edit I want to be able to pass parameters from list child state

> states.list

to

> states.edit

I am unable to get params in edit state. Here is the code:

```
$stateProvider.state('/dashboard', {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: "/partials/dashboard.html"
                })
                .state('states', {
                    abstract:true,
                    url: "/states",
                    templateUrl: "/partials/manage-state.html",
                    controller:"stateManagementContrlr"
                })
                .state('states.list', {
                    url: "",
                    templateUrl: "/partials/state.list.html"
                })
                .state('states.create', {
                    url: "/create",
                    templateUrl: "/partials/create-state.html"
                })
                .state('states.edit', {
                    url: "/edit/:stateId",
                    templateUrl: "/partials/create-state.html",
                })
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
Problem 1: How to get stateParams passed from one child state to another.
Problem 2 : How to trigger a function when state changes?(State change listener good idea ?)

Be carefull I want to handle all this with one controller only .
Please help me
Thanks!

Comment: Listening to the state change events will work, but why do you want to handle this with one controller only?

Comment: I am managing a country states, I am doing a create,update,delete for states only, So one controller can manage all these. But yes, I am unable to get stateParams. Don't know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller is applied to `states`, so when you change from `states.list` to `states.edit` the controller won't die. Just declare a variable in the controller to save your params `var params = {...};`

To trigger function you could either call a function via `ng-click`

```js
$scope.editEntry = function(id) {
  params.id = id;
  $state.go('states.edit');
};
```

or have a look at those state change events: [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

```js
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

**EDIT:**

I just see you can also populate the stateParams with [$state.go()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

```js
$scope.editEntry = function(id) {
  $state.go('state.edit', {stateId: id});
};
```

Comment: page refresh would vanish everything ?

Comment: Okay, answer helps, but what I am thinking now is, let the states manage states only like States > Cities and each have their own scope of manageing. Rest I will do with direct methods and modal Instances. Good?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with state nesting. In general, we can still have list view visible, while navigating to some detail, or edit:

```
.state('states', {
    abstract:true,
    url: "/states",
    templateUrl: "/partials/manage-state.html",
    controller:"stateManagementContrlr"
})
.state('states.list', {
    url: "",
    templateUrl: "/partials/state.list.html"
})
.state('states.list.create', {
    url: "/create",
    templateUrl: "/partials/create-state.html"
})
.state('states.list.edit', {
    url: "/edit/:stateId",
    templateUrl: "/partials/create-state.html",
})
```

In such solution, we need a placeholder "`<div ui-view></div>`" somewhere in the parent `'states.list'` template: "/partials/state.list.html"

Or, we can also replace that with absolute name targeting

```
.state('states.list.create', {
    url: "/create",
    views: {
      '@states': {
          templateUrl: "/partials/create-state.html"
       }
    }
})
.state('states.list.edit', {
    url: "/edit/:stateId",
    views: {
      '@states': {
          templateUrl: "/partials/create-state.html",
       }
    }        
})
```

And what we gain if the parent will be `'states.list'` and `'states.list.edit'` will be a child? Well we can star to share date via native UI-Router inheritance. See more here:

- [Angular UI Router: keeping sibling views around on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23614968/1679310)
- [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)